# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, for-loop

This program shows error in order to get rollingmean output.

```
    dff = pd.Series([ 0.001215,0.001571,0.002944, 0.005101, 0.007357, 0.009988, 0.013653, 0.017936, 0.021971, 0.025590 ])
    dff = pd.DataFrame(dff, columns=['A'])
    avg = dff['A'].rolling(3).mean()
    avg = [x*5 for x in avg] 
    dff['mean'] = avg
    
    listpos = 0 #We use a counter to move over the different data columns
    
    for datapoint in dff.A:
        rollingmean = dff.mean[listpos]
```

After simulation it gives the error message given below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-61e9145fea85> in <module>()
     13 for datapoint in dff.A:
---> 14     rollingmean = dff.mean[listpos] #Get local mean

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Change `dff.mean` to `dff["mean"]`. The error is caused by a name conflict that `dff.mean` is recognized as a library built-in method [pd.DataFrame.mean()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

Comment: Okay. Thank you.